# Iterate over primes using Primes.new in mathn

Tags: ruby, for-loop, primes

I found out `Prime.new` in the `mathn` library in Ruby. I was using it to generate primes for a problem. I want to iterate over all primes between 1 and 1000 using `Primes.new`. Is there any way to use `Prime.new` in a `for` loop or iterate over primes in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also get the n first prime numbers like that :

```
Prime.each(100) do |prime|
  p prime  #=> 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, ...., 97
end
```

cf : http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/b/backports-2.6.1/Prime.html

EDIT : to get the n first prime numbers with above a given value, I would so something like that (this is a draft)

```
require 'mathn'

def prime_numbers_from start, n
  primes = []
  Prime.each(n) do |prime|
    primes << prime if prime > start
  end
  primes
end

prime_numbers_from(10, 30)
# returns => [11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]
```

Comment: What about specifying a start? (Say a high value to begin with?)

Comment: This is perfect, the lower bound is gonna be 1 anyways. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an eloquent way of handling it.

```
ruby-1.9.3-p194 :001 > require 'mathn'
 => true

ruby-1.9.3-p194 :002 > Prime.each(1000) do |i|
ruby-1.9.3-p194 :003 >   puts i
ruby-1.9.3-p194 :004 > end
2
3
.
.
.
991
997
 => nil
```

P.S. `Prime.new` seems to be obsolete.

```
ruby-1.9.3-p194 :005 > Prime.new
Prime::new is obsolete. use Prime::instance or class methods of Prime.
 => #<Prime:0x0000010083ca10 @generator=#<Prime::EratosthenesGenerator...>>
```